# How do I get the full XML or HTML content of an element using ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, api, elementtree

That is, all text and subtags, without the tag of an element itself?

Having

```
<p>blah <b>bleh</b> blih</p>
```

I want

```
blah <b>bleh</b> blih
```

element.text returns "blah " and etree.tostring(element) returns:

```
<p>blah <b>bleh</b> blih</p>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up using:

```
def element_to_string(element):
    s = element.text or ""
    for sub_element in element:
        s += etree.tostring(sub_element)
    s += element.tail
    return s
```

Comment: That would fail when there's no text or no tail, wouldn't it?

Comment: PEZ, yes, it fails when there's no text, just found it by running my code and fixed it. I have many instances of no tail and that doesn't fail. Not sure why.

Comment: Just a nitpick: += on strings is less performant. It's best to accumulate a list of strings and ''.join it at the end.

Comment: You may want to recurse and call `element_to_string` on the sub element again to capture all of the text, i.e `for sub_element in element: s += element_to_string(sub_element)`

Answer (score 11):

ElementTree works perfectly, you have to assemble the answer yourself.  Something like this...

```
"".join( [ "" if t.text is None else t.text ] + [ xml.tostring(e) for e in t.getchildren() ] )
```

Thanks to JV amd PEZ for pointing out the errors.

---

Edit.

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
>>> s= '<p>blah <b>bleh</b> blih</p>\n'
>>> t=xml.fromstring(s)
>>> "".join( [ t.text ] + [ xml.tostring(e) for e in t.getchildren() ] )
'blah <b>bleh</b> blih'
>>>
```

Tail not needed.

Comment: Just pointing out a typo - method name - "finall" which I think should have been "findall". Even if findall is used it results in this http://pastebin.com/f6de9a841. Please revise your answer.

Comment: I'm doing something similar to that, but with a for look. You are actually missing the tail.

Comment: The tail is the extra whitespace after the closing tag of the construct.

Answer (score 3):

These are good answers, which answer the OP's question, particularly if the question is confined to HTML.  But documents are inherently messy, and the depth of element nesting is usually impossible to predict.

To simulate DOM's getTextContent() you would have to use a (very) simple recursive mechanism.

To get just the bare text:

```
def get_deep_text( element ):
    text = element.text or ''
    for subelement in element:
        text += get_deep_text( subelement )
    text += element.tail or ''
    return text
print( get_deep_text( element_of_interest ))
```

To get all the details about the boundaries between raw text:

```
class holder: pass # this is just a way of creating a holder object
holder.element_count = 0
def get_deep_text_w_boundaries(element, depth = 0):
    holder.element_count += 1
    element_no = holder.element_count 
    indent = depth * '  '
    text1 = f'{indent}(el {element_no} tag {element.tag}: text |{element.text or ""}| - attribs: {element.attrib})' 
    print(text1)
    for subelement in element:
        get_deep_text_w_boundaries(subelement, depth + 1)
    text2 = f'{indent}(el {element_no} tag {element.tag} - tail: |{element.tail or ""}|)' 
    print(text2)
get_deep_text_w_boundaries(etree_element)
```

Example output:

```
(el 1 tag source: text |DEVANT LE | - attribs: {})
  (el 2 tag g: text |TRIBUNAL JUDICIAIRE| - attribs: {'style_no': '3'})
  (el 2 tag g - tail: ||)
(el 1 tag source - tail: | DE VERSAILLES|)
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt ElementTree is the thing to use for this. But assuming you have strong reasons for using it maybe you could try stripping the root tag from the fragment:

```
 re.sub(r'(^<%s\b.*?>|</%s\b.*?>$)' % (element.tag, element.tag), '', ElementTree.tostring(element))
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers here are based on the XML parser `ElementTree`, even [PEZ's regex-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/380783/728675) still partially relies on ElementTree.

All those are good and suitable for most use cases but, just for the sake of completeness, it is worth noting that, `ElementTree.tostring(...)` will give you an equivalent snippet, but not always identical to the original payload. If, for some very rare reason, that you want to extract the content as-is, you have to use a pure regex-based solution. [This example](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/pull/120/files) is how I use regex-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is slightly modified of ***Pupeno's*** reply. Here I added encoding type into "tostring". This issue took many hours of mine. I hope this small correction will help others.

```
def element_to_string(element):
        s = element.text or ""
        for sub_element in element:
            s += ElementTree.tostring(sub_element, encoding='unicode')
        s += element.tail
        return s
```

Answer (score -4):

No idea if an external library might be an option, but anyway -- assuming there is one `<p>` with this text on the page, a jQuery-solution would be:

```
alert($('p').html()); // returns blah <b>bleh</b> blih
```