# How can I only extract HTML tags that have <p> with <strong> inside?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup for some web scraping.  I've narrowed my output down to this:

```
[<p><a class="puCloselink" href="javascript:window.close();" id="ctl00_CloseThisPage" onclick="javascript:window.close();" title="Close Window" usesubmitbehavior="false">Close Window</a></p>, <p class="txtBoxAlign">
<span style="display:none"><input id="Location" name="Location" type="hidden"     value="48001"/>
</span>
<input id="newLocation" type="text"/>
<input id="GeoCode" name="GeoCode" type="hidden" value=""/>
<label for="newLocation">Address or ZIP Code (Required): </label>
</p>, <p class="PharmacyNameTxtBox txtBoxAlign">
<input id="PharmacyName" name="PharmacyName" type="text" value=""/>
<label for="PharmacyName">Pharmacy Name: </label>
</p>, <p>
<strong>CVS Pharmacy #</strong><br/>
                        1025 St Clair River Dr <br/>
                        Algonac, MI 48001<br/>
                        1-810-794-4941
                        </p>, <p>
                     Retail
                       </p>, <p>
                        Not applicable
                        </p>, <p>
<strong>Kroger Pharmacy</strong><br/>
                        2600 Pointe Tremble <br/>
                        Algonac, MI 48001<br/>
                        1-810-671-4002
                        </p>, <p>
                     Retail
                       </p>, <p>
                        Not applicable
                        </p>, <p>
<strong>Rite Aid Pharmacy 04943</strong><br/>
                        402 Pointe Tremble Road <br/>
                        Algonac, MI 48001<br/>
                        1-810-794-4985
                        </p>, <p>
                     Retail
                       </p>, <p>
                        Not applicable
                        </p>]
```

As you can see, there are a few "p" tags with "strong" inside them and some "p" tags without "string" inside them.  How can I isolate the entire "p" tag but ONLY for those "p"'s with "strong" contained in them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) to parse and isolate the desired text. Don't forget to put a row tag around your html to give it a root and make it parseable.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

myHTML = '<row> <p><a class="puCloselink" href="javascript:window.close();" id="ctl00_CloseThisPage" onclick="javascript:window.close();" title="Close Window" usesubmitbehavior="false">Close Window</a></p>, <p class="txtBoxAlign"> <span style="display:none"><input id="Location" name="Location" type="hidden"     value="48001"/> </span> <input id="newLocation" type="text"/> <input id="GeoCode" name="GeoCode" type="hidden" value=""/> <label for="newLocation">Address or ZIP Code (Required): </label> </p>, <p class="PharmacyNameTxtBox txtBoxAlign"> <input id="PharmacyName" name="PharmacyName" type="text" value=""/> <label for="PharmacyName">Pharmacy Name: </label> </p>, <p> <strong>CVS Pharmacy #</strong><br/> 1025 St Clair River Dr <br/> Algonac, MI 48001<br/> 1-810-794-4941 </p>, <p> Retail </p>, <p> Not applicable </p>, <p> <strong>Kroger Pharmacy</strong><br/> 2600 Pointe Tremble <br/> Algonac, MI 48001<br/> 1-810-671-4002 </p>, <p> Retail </p>, <p> Not applicable </p>, <p> <strong>Rite Aid Pharmacy 04943</strong><br/> 402 Pointe Tremble Road <br/> Algonac, MI 48001<br/> 1-810-794-4985 </p>, <p> Retail </p>, <p> Not applicable </p> </row>'

root = ElementTree.fromstring(myHTML)

p_elements = root.findall("p")

p_strong_elements = []

for element in p_elements:
   if element.find('strong') is not None:
      p_strong_elements.append(element)

# Borrowed from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380603/how-do-i-get-the-whole-text-of-an-element-using-elementtree
for p_strong_element in p_strong_elements:
    print "<"+p_strong_element.tag+"> "+"".join( [ p_strong_element.text ] + [ ElementTree.tostring(e) for e in p_strong_element.getchildren() ] )+"</"+p_strong_element.tag+"> "
>>>'<p>  <strong>CVS Pharmacy #</strong><br /> 1025 St Clair River Dr <br /> Algonac, MI 48001<br /> 1-810-794-4941 </p> '
>>>'<p>  <strong>Kroger Pharmacy</strong><br /> 2600 Pointe Tremble <br /> Algonac, MI 48001<br /> 1-810-671-4002 </p> '
>>>'<p>  <strong>Rite Aid Pharmacy 04943</strong><br /> 402 Pointe Tremble Road <br /> Algonac, MI 48001<br /> 1-810-794-4985 </p>
```

'

Comment: -1 It's not exactly what OP is asking for. Here you extract all `<strong>` children of `<p>`, he wants to extract `<p>` with at least one `<strong>` child. It's what you may write in jQuery like `p:has(strong)`. Here I'd use `for tag in root.find_all("p/strong") print tag.parent`. Note `.parent` attribute.

Comment: Oh BTW even `.parent` isn't such good because it'll include duplicates (if one `<p>` contains more than one `<strong>`). Raw solution may be to `find("strong")` on each `find_all("p")` and skip if it returns `None` (well performance shouldn't be so good anyway).

Comment: Like Adriano said, I don't want to extract the "string" part of "p", I just want to narrow my results down to all "p" that contain a "strong" HTML tag

Comment: @user2395969 Yes, the array "p_strong_elements" is comprised of only those "p" Element objects which contain a "strong" tag. So just operate on those. The string/print statement is just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: I'm sorry, when I run your code I just get: 
     >>>CVS Pharmacy #
     >>>Kroger Pharmacy
     >>>Rite Aid Pharmacy 04943


when what I want is the full "p" including the both the "strong" and the addresses and phone numbers after the "strong" tag.

Comment: @user2395969 I see, it wasn't clear that you wanted the full string. Please see the above revision.

Answer (score 0):

Found a really easy answer:

```
for i in table:
    if "strong" in str(i):
        address.append(i)
```

Probably not the most elegant way, but it works for me.