# Python extract all text from XML node with child tags

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an XML with the following structure:

```
<mrk mtype="seg" mid="12">line 1 <x id="211"/>
            <x id="212"/> line 2 <x id="213"/>
            <x id="214"/> line 3 <x id="215"/>
</mrk>
```

My code:

```
node = tree.find("mrk")
print(node.text)
```

yields:

> line 1

How do I get the full text ("line 1 line 2 line 3") using Python 3.5 and ElementTree?

## UPDATE

This is a bit different from [How do I get the full XML or HTML content of an element using ElementTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380603/how-do-i-get-the-whole-text-of-an-element-using-elementtree) because I need the text without any child tags.

The easiest SOLUTION I found is:

```
"".join(node.itertext())
```

Comment: Did you try printing just `node`, or see what other attributes it has?

Comment: When I print node I get something like: `"<Element 'mrk' at 0x000001C6C9105B38>`

Comment: `print(node.attrib)` gives `{'mid': '12', 'mtype': 'seg'}`